# How to get elapsed time when running a test case in Katalon?

Tags: java, katalon-studio, elapsedtime, katalon

When running a test case in Katalon then it shows elapsed time of that test case in the log viewer and I want to get that elapsed time automatically to output into a custom report. How can I get this elapsed time?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Mate Mrse's answer, let's do the following:

### [Create Custom Keyword](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/katalon-studio/keywords/custom-keywords/introduction-to-custom-keywords-in-katalon-studio), or something similar

Let's call this Custom Keyword `ElapsedTimeUtil`:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import groovy.time.TimeDuration

package com.tarang.utils

public class ElapsedTimeUtil { 
    private static final ElapsedTimeUtil _instance;

    private Date startTime;

    public static ElapsedTimeUtil GetInstance() {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new ElapsedTimeUtil();

        return _instance;
    }

    private ElapsedTimeUtil() {
        // this is deliberately left empty, for semantic reasons
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        this.startTime = new Date();
    }

    public TimeDuration getElapsedTime() {
        return TimeCategory.minus(new Date(), this.startTime);
    }
}
```

Notice that, we are using Groovy's built-in `TimeDuration` class ([here is documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeDuration.html)).

### Set this Custom Keyword up with [Test Case Listener](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/katalon-studio/create-test-cases/test-fixtures-and-test-listeners-test-hooks-in-katalon-studio)

Follow [the linked instructions](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/katalon-studio/create-test-cases/test-fixtures-and-test-listeners-test-hooks-in-katalon-studio) to create your Test Listener.

Then, we do the following:

#### Initialization

In your `@BeforeTestCase` hook, add the following:

```
ElapsedTimeUtil.GetInstance().startTimer();
```

#### Teardown

This is where you get the elapsed time for your custom report. You can choose to do this one of two ways:

- in the `@AfterTestCase` hook, or
- in the `tearDownTestCase` hook of your test suite (delete the `(skipped = true)` from the annotation)

Either way, add the following:

```
ElapsedTimeUtil.GetInstance().getElapsedTime(); // TODO: pass this to your report util keyword
```

The former is preferred for completeness, and will happen regardless of test suite or test case

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using the script view.

Do this:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import groovy.time.TimeDuration

start = new Date()

// execute the test

end = new Date()

TimeDuration td = TimeCategory.minus(end, start)
println td
```

Comment: I see your answer, and will do you one better...